# Shiny dynamical modalDialog render* difftime

Tags: shiny, modal-dialog, difftime

In an attempt to solve this question
[R Shiny: display elapsed time while function is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61460611/r-shiny-display-elapsed-time-while-function-is-running),
I tried several things, and I have questions about the modal dialog.

Here is a MWE

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton('run', 'Run')
    ),

    mainPanel(
     tableOutput("result")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  N <- 4

  rv_time <- reactiveValues(
    startTime = Sys.time(), 
    endTime = Sys.time()
  )

  output$start <- renderUI({
    line1 <- paste("Start at:", format(Sys.time(), format = "%R"))
    line2 <- "Be patient, it can takes some time"
    HTML(paste(line1, line2, sep = "<br/>"))
  })

  result_val <- reactiveVal()
  observeEvent(input$run,{
    showModal(modalDialog(htmlOutput("start"), footer = NULL))

    rv_time$startTime <- Sys.time()

    result_val(NULL)
    for(i in 1:N){
      # Long Running Task
      Sys.sleep(1)
    }
    result_val(quantile(rnorm(1000)))

    rv_time$endTime <- Sys.time()

    # removeModal()
    showModal(modalDialog(textOutput("timer"), footer = modalButton("Cancel")))
  })

  output$result <- renderTable({
    result_val()
  })

  output$timer <- renderText({
    paste0("Executed in: ", round(difftime(rv_time$endTime, rv_time$startTime, units = "mins"),2), " minutes")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If you click on the "Run" button the first time, you will see that the first dialog message is empty, the one will the running time works.

If you click another time then on the "Run" button, then everything works. I don't know why this happens.

I could have avoid the call of `output$start`, and then I would have no problem. But I'd like to understand why it doesn't work, and also, instead of displaying the starting time, I want to display a "dynamical" timer.

Once one clicks on the "Run" button, the dialog box shows the elapsed time since the beginning of the run. So I thought that I need to use an intermediate `output$start` (I tried to include `invalideLater` but failed so far). I might be wrong though.

Not related to that, I have a question about `difftime`. I had to use the option `unit = "mins"` so I can add the unit behind, because otherwise it doesn't display the unit by default. This example runs in 4 seconds, it would be better than it prints 4 secondes, instead of 0.07 minutes. Is there a way to adapt the unit? (the real code I did runs in several minutes, and possibly hours).

Answer (score 1):

`htmlOutput("start")` is not calculated when it is hidden. If you add the line

```
outputOptions(output, "start", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

then it will be shown at the first hit on the button.

Comment: Thank you, it works! But why did it work the seconf time then? It was not hidden anymore? I am confused about that